# PHP header issue

Tags: php, xml, http-headers, mime-types, atom-feed

I have set HTTP header in PHP as:

```php
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
```

And I got following response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feedback>
    <result>False</result>
</feedback>
```

But when I check headers, it says the response type is `application/atom+xml` . I need this in `application/xml` format. What could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at the raw headers and not via a browser?

Comment: I checked the issue remain same. Actually the XML uses for iOS development. When I debug through xCode I got same response header

Comment: maybe there is a problem with file encoding, bom signature or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason why that shouldn't work. I've just tried a simple test case with that xml and it certainly works for me.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feedback>
    <result>False</result>
</feedback>
```

Either there is more to your php that you're not showing us, or possibly there is something misconfigured in your server software.

**Update**

Based on the information you provided in your answer, I'd say you could fix this by changing your root element to anything that doesn't start with `<feed`. As I said in my comment, something is incorrectly interpreting this as being an Atom feed and rewriting the content-type.

That said, there are assumedly other strings (e.g. `<rss`) that might trigger other rewrites of the content-type, so it would be preferable if you could track down whatever system was responsible for the error and get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer friend. Yeah. Other responses works fine. And there is no hidden php. That's why I am struggle.

Comment: So does that simple test case I provided work for you or not?

Comment: Actually it didn't work. I changed like this.

<?php
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
?>

Still getting same header.

Comment: Then it seems to me there must be something wrong with your server setup. Perhaps it might help if you could provide something like your php.ini or server configuration files (although beware of disclosing anything that might have security implications for you).

Comment: One other possibility might be if there is a gateway or proxy between you and the server that might be doing some kind of content rewriting. Is that possible? Is it something you can reproduce on a local server instance?

Comment: Thanks James. I will further check things you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what the technical explanation. But changing the XML content fixed my issue. It was a slight change. I just added a top level branch element,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
<feedback>
    <result>True</result>
</feedback>
</data>
```

Comment: Interesting. I suspect something (either your server, or a proxy) detected that the first element of your document started with `<feed` and interpreted that as being an Atom feed. As a result, it thought it would be a good idea to rewrite the content-type as `application/atom+xml`. Whoever is responsible for that code should be shot.

Comment: Thanks James. I think exactly that kind of thing happen. I already informed the server guy to check that.